# PHP SQL UPDATE works in FF and CHROME but not in IE?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

the below code works perfectly in FF and CHROME but not in IE. Please help. I have commented out my santize functions as i thought they might be affecting it, but it still does the same.... nothing in IE. 
Thank you in advance for any assistance.

```
<?php 

//IF UPDATE BUCKET CHANGE STATUS...
if(isset($_POST['updatebucket'])){


 $complete = $_POST["complete"];
 $bucketid = $_POST["bucketid"];

//$complete = sanitizeone($_POST["complete"], "plain");
//$complete = strip_word_html($complete);
//$bucketid = sanitizeone($_POST["bucketid"], "plain");
//$bucketid = strip_word_html($bucketid);

if ($complete=="1")
  $complete = "0";
else
  $complete = "1";

$updatebucket = "UPDATE membersbuckets SET complete = '$complete' WHERE userid = '$userid' AND bucketid = '$bucketid'"; 
mysql_query($updatebucket);
}
?>
```

and the front end....

```
<? if ($complete=="1") {
    echo "<form action='' method='post' name='updatebucket'><input name='complete' type='hidden' value=" .$complete. " /><input name='userid' type='hidden' value=" .$userid. " /><input name='bucketid' type='hidden' value=" .$bucketid. " /><input type='image' name='updatebucket' value='updatebucket' src='images/tick.png' /></form>";
    }else{
    echo "<form action='' method='post' name='updatebucket'><input name='complete' type='hidden' value=" .$complete. " /><input name='userid' type='hidden' value=" .$userid. " /><input name='bucketid' type='hidden' value=" .$bucketid. " /><input type='image' name='updatebucket' value='updatebucket' src='images/cross.png' /></form>";  
}
?>
```

Dan

Comment: MySQL has nothing to do with the browser; browsers = client, PHP+MySQL = server

Comment: Backend code wouldn't be processed in different ways for different browsers as this is processed on the server. Post your HTML

Comment: @Daniel Hanly: But surprisingly enough, there is enough difference in form handling that different browsers will send a different set of data from the same form, which makes it seem that the input is the same, yet the output isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should post your front-end, not back-end (since it's pretty much not browser-dependant).

Your HTML probably isn't valid.

Edit:

Yep, IE doesn't take value for image type of input. It only sends the x & y (field_name_x, field_name_y) and totally discards the original "value" attribute.

Try with a hidden input instead.

Comment: So put the name='updatebucket' value='updatebucket' in another hidden input and just have the image as the "submit" ? or do i have to get rid of the image as the submit button all together?
Thanks.

Comment: just add a hidden field, keep the image but for submit only :)

Comment: Thanks Kemo. Just what i needed!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `input type='image'` doesn't send the value when used from IE. You'll need another hidden field:

```
<input type='hidden' name='updatebucket' value='updatebucket' />
<input type='image' src='images/tick.png' />
```

That way, the `updatebucket` parameter will be posted to the server, regardless of the browser used.

The assumption here was that all browsers handle HTML forms the same way (and they don't); that's why I keep Eric Lawrence's excellent [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) around - it can diff two HTTP requests, so you'll see the difference between the browsers immediately.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to check for `$_POST[{image-element-name}_x}]` (in this case `$_POST['updatebucket_x']`. All browsers will send the x/y coordinates of the image element as `updatebucket.x` & `updatebucket.y`, and PHP silently (and frustratingly) alters the `updatebucket.x` to `updatebucket_x`. Then again, you only need this is clicking different input type=submit / type=image elements would alter the action taken, otherwise the previous solution of a hidden element as previously suggested would do.